# Python: most idiomatic way to set a variable conditionally?

Tags: python, coding-style

Let's say I have a condition that evaluate a to a boolean, `condition`, and I want to set the variable `foo` to a value depending on that condition.

I could write in several different ways (for simplicity, let's assume `some_value` and `some_other_value` are constants and not function calls). Here's a way:

```
foo = None
if condition:
  foo = some_value
else:
  foo = some_other_value
```

This approach is nice because `foo` is clearly declared at the top; it is however a bit verbose. We could write it more simply as:

```
if condition:
  foo = some_value
else:
  foo = some_other_value
```

This saves us an assignment, but some programmers could find the exact nature of `foo`'s scope unclear.

Another way could be:

```
foo = some_other_value
if condition:
  foo = some_value
```

This is more concise and saves us a branch; however it could be misleading for someone quickly reading over the code.

Is one of those ways preferred for style, or execution speed? (although I suspect here the performance gains would be minimal, if not null)
Or is another fourth way of writing this code recommended?

Comment: Use the `if`/`else` with no predeclaration; people should know what you mean. Performance doesn’t matter much, but I imagine it would also be the fastest.

Answer (score 3):

`foo = some_value if condition else some_other_value`

Comment: I thought ternary operators were considered "unpythonic"?

Comment: I dont see how this is better than the OP's last example.

Comment: @bitgarden, if they were unpythonic, Guido wouldn't have added them ;-)  Seriously, short, easy-to-understand ternarys are quite Pythonic.  Where they suck is when programmers get overly enchanted with "1-liner disease".

Comment: ternary operators are certainly not "unpythonic". If the condition is simple, and the resulting line is readable, this can be far more readable than a compound statement. Additionally, these expressions can be used in generator/list/dict comprehensions where others can't, making them extremely "pythonic".

Comment: I think some long-term Python programmers (myself included) developed knee-jerk bad reactions to ternary constructions when using 2.4 or earlier, where it wasn't supported. I saw a lot of ugly hacks using `and` and `or`, which definitely were unpythonic. Now it's perfectly legitimate, at least as long as the code is readable, but I still never think to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Although this can be done with the ternary operator

```
foo = some_value if condition else some_other_value
```

Guido never did like the ternary operator, so it can hardly be called "Pythonic"

I think this is the preferred way and compatible with every version of Python out there

```
if condition:
  foo = some_value
else:
  foo = some_other_value
```

The difference between that and

```
foo = some_other_value
if condition:
  foo = some_value
```

is in the case the `some_other_value` needs to be computed (by a function say) and you wish to avoid calling the function unnecessarily

Answer (score 0):

Python has a ternary operator

```
foo = ifTrue if predicate else ifFalse
```

predicate is any boolean-valued expression.  For example

```
def abs(x):
    return x if x > 0 else -x
```

It is compact, economical, and easily understood.  Be careful to use parens on the predicate if it is at all complex.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I prefer the ternary operator:

```
foo = baz if quux() else bar
```

But is there a performance reason to prefer one over the other? **No**.

```
In [15]: %timeit foo = 2 if random.randint(0,1) else 3
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.69 µs per loop

In [16]: %%timeit
   ....: if random.randint(0,1):
   ....:     foo = 2
   ....: else:
   ....:     foo = 3
   ....:
100000 loops, best of 3: 1.6 µs per loop

In [17]: %%timeit foo = 0
if random.randint(0,1):
    foo = 2
else:
    foo = 3
   ....:
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.59 µs per loop
```